# Reason to upgrade to elastic search to 5.x from 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Currently i have a system running elastic search 2.4 with 40-50 indices holding very little data  (may be few hundreds of documents) used for data logging. There is a ask to add additional feature to index upto 50 billion documents. Now as this is new requirement, there is also thinking to update to 5.x but need solid data points as why this cannot be done on 2.4x.

1. Firstly community support available for 2.x? As 5.x is latest, would users of issues be encouraged to move to 5.x rather than solving in 2.x?
2. Are there major changes in architectural wise leading to performance improvements on 
   a) heap
   b) CPU consumption
   c) Anything else?
   d) support for spark or hadoop for batch processing

Comment: The main reason would be that 2.4 will be [EOL at the end of February 2018](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) so it's not a question of whether 2.4 can support 50 billion documents or not (it definitely can if tuned correctly) but you're always encouraged to use one of the latest versions if you want to benefit from bug fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: Thanks Val. This is very good point which i missed out and is very good reason to move to 5.x. In general is there any issues with back support of index of 2.x in 5.x? This is more for understanding purpose

Comment: I suggest you go through the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) and look carefully at each change that might impact your specific environment and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Many reasons. Even if you don't care about support , [Performance enhancements](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-5-0-0-released) in 5.x is good reason to migrate.

ES 5  uses newer version of Lucene in addition to several improvements in ES code itself.

Also since you have very few documents now  - this is the right time to upgrade ; It will be much easier / time saving than upgrading a larger index.